# Retrieving date values from Active Directory entry

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve date values from my directory entries, but I'm getting a `COM-Object` which I don't know to handle. After retrieval I'd like to convert it to a C# `DateTime` object.

I'm using the using `System.DirectoryServices Class` and this is how I access my AD entry:

```
var e = entry.Poperties["pwdLastSet"].Value;
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19181/Find-LastLogon-Across-All-Windows-Domain-Controlle The required Lib is called "Active DS Type Library" and can be found under "COM" in the Reference Managers

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which doesn't require adding the ActiveDS lib to be referenced at all is to use the 'invokeGet' runtime reflection method which invokes a call on the system's AD interface.

Example below:

```
DateTime pwd_last_set = (DateTime)entry.InvokeGet("PasswordLastSet");
```

This gets around any 32bit/64bit issues if your code is being distributed to different systems and you referenced the System32 or SysWOW64 version of the ActiveDS lib.